# how to get the data into my Bean class with the help of RestTemplate object?

Tags: android, exception, post, resttemplate

I am new to work with RestTemplates.In my application i am trying to send request by using  post method as follows

```
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("application","json",Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        requestHeaders.add("username", "sai3");
        requestHeaders.add("password", "x");
        requestHeaders.add("device_id", device_id);

        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestHeaders);
        // Create a new RestTemplate instance
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());

`       restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        ResponseEntity<GetResponseBean> responseEntity1 = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, GetResponseBean.class);
        obj = responseEntity1.getBody();

        Log.v("GetDataResponse", "result message : "+obj);
```

For the above code i have used `"spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar"`,`"spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar"` and `"jackson-all-1.9.8.jar"`

If I use `ResponseEntity` type is String then it is returning fine response but If I change `ResponseEntity` type `GetResponseBean` type then i am getting error as follow :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [com.example.springsxmlposting.GetResponseBean] and content type [text/html]
```

`GetResponseBean` class as follows:

```
public class GetResponseBean {

    String result = null;
    String message = null;

    public void setmResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getmResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setmMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getmMessage() {
        return message;
    }

}
```

How can i get the data into my bean class (`GetResponseBean`) please any body help me

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem relies in your server. You're sending `content-type: application/json` but as you can see in your error, it states that the response you get is `text/html` and not `application/json`.

My guess is that the response you're getting back is an error html page that states that you don't have a request that returns `application/json`. You can try and use an external tool for sending the request to the server. Do a POST request with the same headers and I bet you'll get an HTML error page.